# Two JARs on buildpath with identical method names but different constructors. How can I specify which JAR's method to use?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, stanford-nlp

I am building a tool from several different open source libraries.  My buildpath is in the following order:

My first JAR file, `stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar`, contains a package called `edu.stanford.nlp.process`, which has the `Morphology.class` class.

[image]

My second JAR file, `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar`, contains an identical package name (`edu.stanford.nlp.process`), and an identical class name `Morphology.class`.

[image]

In both JARS, inside their respective `Morphology` classes there exists a method called `stem()`.  However, the constructors for these methods are different. I want to use the `stem(String, String)` method from my second JAR file, but since the import statement (`import edu.stanford.nlp.process.Morphology;`) does not specify which JAR to use, I get an error since it thinks the first JAR on the buildpath is the one I want to implement.

I don't want to change the order of my buildpath since it would throw off my other method calls.

How can I specify which JAR's `Morphology` class to use?  Is there an import statement that specifies the JAR, along with the package.class?

EDIT:  What about a way to combine my two JARs so that the two `Morphology` classes merge, giving me two methods with different constructors?

Comment: JAR files are searched in the order they appear in the classpath.

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by using a custom class loader, but perhaps the simpler approach would be to create a new JAR containing JUST the classes you want, and put it earlier in the search order.

Comment: That's a great idea, please see my edit.

Comment: You can't (without a lot of ugly bytecode-level gymnastics) "combine" the two classes.  You must pick one or the other.

Comment: You should note that your issue isn't so much two jars as it is two identically-named (but non-identical) classes, both of which you want to use.

Comment: (One odd thing is that you keep focusing on the identical *method* names.  It's the identical *class* names that's the problem.  Different classes can have identical method names without causing a problem, but you can't (easily) have identical class names.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Half the battle here has been expressing the problem.

Comment: Can you be clear:  Do you ONLY want methods from the second version, or do you also need methods from the first version (that are not found in the second)?

Comment: I need methods from both, but the problem is that the second JAR's `Morphology` class is inaccessible due to the order of my buildpath.   The issue is accessing the `stem(String, String)` method from `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar`, since the `stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar` is listed first in the buildpath.

Comment: If you need methods from both you're sunk.  You can't have the same object respond to both sets of methods, even if you do an evil class loader trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved simply by using the `lemma(String word, String tag)` method in the current CoreNLP's Morphology class:

```
String word = ...;
String tag = ...;
String lemma = morphology.lemma(word, tag);
WordTag wt = new WordTag(lemma, tag);
```

When the class was revised a couple of years ago, the method you're looking for was deleted. The feeling was that with most of the Stanford NLP code moving to using `CoreLabel`s, methods that return `WordTag` are less useful (though deleting all such methods is still a work in progress).

Answer (score 2):

The default `ClassLoader` will only load one of the jars, ignoring the second one, so this can't be done out of the box. Maybe a custom `ClassLoader` can help.

For more info about `ClassLoader`s start from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader).

Good luck!

**EDIT**: We are looking at some horrible packaging choices causing as side effect this Jar Hell here. The author of this ["Ark Twitter"](https://github.com/brendano/ark-tweet-nlp) library decided it was a good idea to release a JAR artifact that includes a third party library (the Stanford NLP library). This leads to unnecessarily tight coupling between Ark Twitter and the specific version of the Stanford NLP library used by it. This is a very bad practice that should be discouraged in any case: this violates the whole idea about transitive dependencies.

**EDIT** (continued): One possible (and hopefully working) solution is to rebuild the Ark Twitter JAR so that it does *not* include the aforementioned library but only its own code (basically the [cmu.arktweetnlp](https://github.com/brendano/ark-tweet-nlp/tree/master/src) package only) and hoping that the version of NLP required by your project works with Ark Twitter. Ideally you should submit a pull request to the author of the library but in the meantime you can get away with un-jarring and re-jarring the existing JAR file.

**EDIT 2**: Looking at the JAR file again, it's much worse that I originally thought: **ALL** the dependencies are repackaged in the released JAR file. This is really the worst possible solution for releasing a library. Good luck.

Comment: How do I use a `ClassLoader` to specify the JAR->Package->Class->Method?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia page and the documentation. Maybe OSGi can help but in the best case scenario you can only load the two different JARs from different packages, not in the same one. You can probably unload the one and reload the other but you can't use both at the same time form the same class/package. This is a limitations of Java. The real question is: can you do this in a different way? Why do you have the exact same class in those two packages? Is it two versions of the same? If so, you should choose one.

Comment: PS: I'm not a `ClassLoader` expert by any chance so you're gonna have to RTM.

Comment: Using a custom class loader (and not shooting yourself in the foot) is non-trivial.  It requires some study of the topic.  (It may seem simple at first blush, but it's easy to time yourself into a knot.)

Comment: Agreed. That's why I highly recommend to find a different solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no other solution.  I need the stemmer from `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar`, but the Dependency Parser from `stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar`.

Comment: Again though, why are there two versions of the same exact class? Is it just an accident or are they two of the same?

Comment: I've added screenshots that should help clear up why there are two versions of the same class.  One JAR ships with `stem(String)`, while the other ships with `stem(String, String)`.

Comment: Yeah these look like different versions of the same class. Very bad code smell to try and use them both if you ask me. Does the first JAR file only contain the one file or the whole library?

Comment: On second thought, I think you are looking at a non-problem. Remove the first JAR from your classpath and you will get the class yow want with both overloaded versions of the `stem` method. That should do what you need.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is and updated my answer accordingly. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As several others pointed out above, it is possible to tweak Java's classloader mechanism to load classes from certain places… but this is not what you are looking for, believe me.

You hit a known problem. Instead of worrying how to tell Java to use a class from one JAR and not from the other, you should consider using a different version of ArkTweet.

**Fetch the [ArkTweet JAR from Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cedu.cmu.cs%7Cark-tweet-nlp%7C0.3.2%7Cjar). It does not contain Stanford classes.**

When you notice that people package third-party classes in their JARs, I'd recommend pointing out to them that this is generally not a good idea and to encourage them to refrain from doing so. If a project provides a runnable fat-jar including all dependencies, that is fine. But, it should not be the only JAR they provide. A plain JAR or set of JARs without any third-party code should also be offered. In the rare cases that third-party code was modified and must be included, it should be done under the package namespace of the provider, not of the original third-party.

Finally, for real solutions to building modular Java applications and handling classloader isolation, check out one of the several [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) implementations or project [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. This is a weakness of Java, that cannot be simply solved. You should use only one of the libraries. Having both on the classpath will make java always select the first one.

This problem is named as [Jar hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell).

Answer (score 1):

The order in the buildpath generally determines the order in which the classloader will search for the class. In general, though, you don't want duplicates of the same class in your build path--and it sure doesn't seem like ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar should have a edu.stanford package within it.

Comment: `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar` was built off of an older version of `stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar`.  Unfortunately, the packages included in `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar` do not contain the class methods that I need.

Comment: "built off of" doesn't usually imply "includes bits from." If it's a fork, that's one thing, but it sure doesn't look like one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misspoke. In order for the novel methods  within `ark-tweet-nlp-0.3.2.jar` to work properly and independently, the creators included several necessary packages from Stanford CoreNLP library.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a class, it's loaded at given address, and that address is then placed in the header of objects created from the class, so that (among other things) the methods in the class can be located.

So if you somehow load ClassA, with method abc(String), from zip file XYZ.zip, that loads into address 12345.  Then (using a class loader trick) you load another ClassA, with method abc(String, String), from zip file ZYX.zip, and that loads into address 67890.

Now create an instance of the first ClassA.  In its header will the class address 12345.  If you could somehow attempt to invoke the method abc(String,String) on that class, that method would not be found in the class at 12345.  (In actuality, you will not even be able to attempt the call, since the verifier will stop you because, to it, the two classes are entirely different and you're trying to use one where the other is called for, just as if their names were entirely different.)